# How can I render a ball with equirectangular camera?

Tags: rendering, camera, light, noise-reduction

Firstly, I'm a first time user for Blender. I want a equirectangular image so that I can create a texture to use on a sphere object on my Unity project. I'm searching and trying for hours. Here what I came.

I found a soccer ball model. [image]

The idea is to place a camera inside and center of the ball. Change camera view to Equirectangular and render in order to get a 360° image of it.

However, my render result is like that.
[image]

I placed lights inside the ball but it still looks awful. I'm not sure the problem is about lighting because it's not dark, it just noisy and black-and-white. How can I fix this? Is there a way to render in Solid View, which is really good looking?

[This is the .blend file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-YVymtrEsoITRmCeNfQD4w8aofr0VqHI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This may be a problem caused by ambient occlusion. Is that setting turned on?

Comment: @TheLabCat https://imgur.com/H7Uv3ae there isn't any. I added and poked up a bit but no change.

Comment: With the camera on the inside of the ball the normals would be the wrong way, and you're capturing some inner geometry that is constructed that way to give the outward appearance of the segments of a soccer ball.